# En littérature « merveilleuse » ou « du merveilleux » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, adjectifs, terminologie, littérature, substantivation

Comment utilise-t-on le (« nom du ») genre littéraire [*merveilleux*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8360324), soit le « genre littéraire incorporant un ou plusieurs éléments d'irrationnel (créatures surnaturelles, utilisation de pouvoirs magiques, etc.) qui s'insèrent de façon harmonieuse dans la réalité du monde imaginaire présenté » (GDT) avec le nom *littérature*, en ellipse avec la préposition *en* : *en littérature merveilleuse/du [merveilleux](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/merveilleux)* ? Sait-on à peu près depuis quand on utilise *merveilleux* pour faire référence à ce genre littéraire ?

Comment: Je commente faute de savoir répondre dans le cadre demandé par l'OP. Avant de devenir un genre, le *merveilleux* est une **figure de rhétorique** connue depuis au moins Aristote. Il faudra attendre le **surréalisme et André Breton** pour développer cette figure et que cela devienne un genre littéraire à part entière. Et depuis, on fourre tout dedans, à commencer par Rabelais, le cycle Arthurien...

Comment: la définition me fait fortement penser à la définition de la littérature fantastique : "intrusion du naturel dans un cadre réaliste" (ne pas confondre fantastique et fantasy, le dernier étant dans un cadre imaginaire). Avec ngram, je ne trouve rien pour "littérature merveilleuse", ni pour "littérature du merveilleux", ni même "roman merveilleux", alors que "littérature/roman fantastique" est bien présent.

Comment: @radouxju Le terme présenté dans la question est proposé par l'OQLF en remplacement de *fantasy*. Il semble que le merveilleux n'ait pas été considéré digne de séparation en sous-genres par cet organisme. Dans la réalité éditoriale française, des collections de fantasy et de science-fiction existent, et il me semble normal de penser que l'on puisse au moins considérer de séparer Asimov, Tolkien et Perrault, ce qui est bien le cas chez plusieurs éditeurs. La France, elle, a proposé *fantaise*, qui me semble convenable, mais n'a néanmoins pas semblé s'imposer très fortement non plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La quatrième édition du Dictionnaire de l’Académie française (1762) décrit déjà une substantivation de l’adjectif *merveilleux* en ces termes :

> **MERVEILLEUX**, s'emploie aussi au substantif, & signifie, Ce qu'il y a de merveilleux, de surprenant, d'admirable dans un Poëme, ou Épique, ou Dramatique. *Le merveilleux doit être joint au vraisemblable.* Il se dit aussi De ce qu'il y a de vif, de noble & d'élevé dans les expressions, dans le style.

Par la suite, le terme est davantage étoffé, et dans la huitième édition (1935), on peut lire :

> **MERVEILLEUX** s'emploie comme nom dans le langage de la littérature pour signifier l'Intervention des êtres surnaturels dans un poème épique ou dramatique. *Le merveilleux de la mythologie. Il a emprunté le merveilleux de son épopée à la magie, à la féerie. Dans ce poème, le merveilleux se réduit à l'emploi de personnages allégoriques. On distingue le merveilleux chrétien et le merveilleux païen.* Il signifie aussi Ce qui, dans un événement, dans un récit, s'éloigne de l'ordre naturel et du cours ordinaire des choses. Voilà le merveilleux de l'aventure, de l'histoire.

Déjà il y a près d’un siècle, donc, on parle du merveilleux chrétien et du merveilleux païen, et sans aucun doute aussi du merveilleux musulman, qui ne fut pas nommé, mais que l’on perçoit immanquablement à la lecture des *Mille et une nuits*, par exemple.

En emploi absolu pour désigner un certain type de littérature, il semble sensé d’affirmer en suivant le commentaire d’[aCOSwt](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/17526/) sous la question qu’il existe des œuvres antérieures à l’établissement officielle ou même officieuse de la désignation, puisque déjà Homère en incorporait à ses récits, et que Lucien de Samosate (120-180) se fit même un devoir dans son [*Histoire véritable*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoires_vraies_(Lucien)), de ne jamais même toucher à la réalité, mais de composer une aventure rocambolesque qui soit du début à la fin un tissu de mensonges. Il n’est d’ailleurs guère secret quant à sa volonté : il la déclare très explicitement dès [son introduction](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Histoire_v%C3%A9ritable_(Lucien)).

Et aussi en ligne avec aCOSwt, que l’établissement d’un type littéraire appelé merveilleux a pu servir ultérieurement de fourre-tout à de nouveaux types de merveilleux qui ne partagent pas forcément beaucoup de traits en commun, outre leur utilisation d’*« un ou plusieurs éléments d'irrationnel (créatures surnaturelles, utilisation de pouvoirs magiques, etc.) qui s'insèrent de façon harmonieuse dans la réalité du monde imaginaire présenté »*. Les contes de fées, les contes folkloriques, les légendes et croyances diverses, les fables et contes animaliers existent depuis longtemps. Du point de vue de la langue française, on pourrait dire qu’ils existent depuis toujours. Qu’ils aient été englobé par l’appelation de *merveilleux* est tout naturel : on devrait même plutôt dire que l’appelation fut créée pour eux.

Le fantastique était présent dans certains de ces récits. L’apparition d’une littérature spécialisée en fantastique, et plus récemment d’un courant particulier coulant vers l’horreur, semble marquer les confins de la notion de merveilleux.

Néanmoins, de nouveaux types de merveilleux ont été explorés ou définis plus récemment, et il a semblé naturel de les incorporer sous la vaste bannière du merveilleux. On peut penser par exemple à la [science-fiction](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science-fiction) et à la [fantasy](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantasy) (ou [fantaisie](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000017735178&dateTexte=&categorieLien=id)).

On pourrait tenter de tracer des parallèles avec d’autres types de littérature, afin d’y trouver une manière de désigner la littérature du merveilleux.

- **Le surréalisme,** pour lequel existe un adjectif (surréaliste), pourrait sembler un bon point de départ. Il y a cependant un hic : si l’adjectif est utilisé à toutes les sauces, le surréalisme demeure habituellement LE surréalisme, tel que décrit par André Breton. Et le nom a servi à la création de l’adjectif, tout le contraire du merveilleux.
- **Le policier** peut-être ? Il existe un nom et un adjectif *policier*. On parle communément de *littérature policière*, de *romans policiers* et par métonymie ***du*** roman policier pour désigner le genre et l’ensemble des œuvres romanesques s’y rattachant. L’ennui ici est que merveilleux peut qualifier correctement des choses bien éloignées d’une œuvre d’art, fut-elle littéraire ou simplement picturale. Un coucher de soleil, une période de vacances bien méritée, un résultat scolaire, un nouveau modèle de semelles de bottes, une vieille tête de hache toute rouillée datant de 1500 ans, une dent de dinosaure, pourraient tous être qualifiés de merveilleux. Bien sûr, un policier n’est pas forcément une œuvre d’art non plus, mais la versatilité de *policier* est beaucoup plus restreinte que celle de *merveilleux*.

Que faire alors ? On peut bien sûr parler de ***littérature merveilleuse***, qui dans un contexte adéquat sera aisément compréhensible, et probablement jamais confondue avec la *merveilleuse littérature réaliste déconstructiviste française du XXe siècle* ou quelque autre *merveilleuse littérature de gare*. Mais l’option ***littérature du merveilleux*** aura l’avantage de n’être pas ambiguë et de ne pas laisser même soupçonner que l’on attribue une simple épithète d’appréciation à la littérature en général. On pourrait cependant alors se demander de quel merveilleux il est question *(le merveilleux chrétien ? païen ? du conte de fée ? du folklore inuit ? d’autre chose encore ?)*.

Comment: Merci ! Une merveilleuse réponse !